# How to divide a variable multiple times

Tags: java

I would appreciate any help.

So the prompt was to create a program with integers userNum and x as inputs and have the output be userNum divided by x a certain amount of times(in my case, let's say 4).
This is the code I have so far which works finely for dividing userNum by X but it only does it once when I need it be done however many times is specified. Any advice?

```
public class LabProgram
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      int userNum;
      int x;
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      userNum = scnr.nextInt();
      x = scnr.nextInt();

      System.out.println(userNum / x);


   }
}
```

If my input 2000 2, I only get 1000 as an output when my required output is 1000 500 250 125.

Comment: You need to learn the language features. To do the repetitive task, you need to use loops or recursion. For the fix time, better use loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use some form of loop such as a `for` loop.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      int userNum;
      int x;
      int times;
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      userNum = scnr.nextInt();
      x = scnr.nextInt();
      times = scnr.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
          userNum /= x;
      }
      System.out.println(userNum);
   }
```

You may want to make `userNum` a `double` as integer division will result in truncation of decimal values by removing the decimal portion.

Comment: Ah, so I put in your code of ```userNum /= x;``` and wrote something like this: ```System.out.println(userNum /= x);``` and that seemed to do the trick! Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's time for you to use something called a 'loop'.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

}
```

Put some parts of your code inside this loop and magic will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here, You can use loops here if you want to divide number 4 times then you can use for loop and if you want to divide UserNum until value of UserNum is not equals to 0 then you can use while loop.